# instasharper API wont get inbox?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, instagram-api

im trying to make a window application where you can send instagram messages, however my code cant fetch the inbox. :. heres some of the code:

```
 `    
   if (loginreq.Succeeded)
            {
            string user = "kristian_grey.memes";
            Console.WriteLine("logged in!");
            //THIS LINE BELOW
            var inboxThreads = await api.GetDirectInboxAsync();
            if (!inboxThreads.Succeeded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to get inbox");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var thread in inboxThreads.Value.Inbox.Threads)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Threadname: {thread.Title}, users: {thread.Users.Count}");
            }`
```

heres the error:

`Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "6700803485145306816" to type 'System.Guid'. Path 'inbox.threads[0].items[0].client_context', line 1, position 1779. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Guid.`

Comment: Can you show us the code for `GetDirectInboxAsync`?  Sounds like you have a property declared as a `Guid` but the value is actually a `string` in the JSON.

Comment: im not sure what you mean, ill give you my whole script that involves this, so here :) :

Comment: https://pastebin.com/i7YQhh3i

Comment: i think what its saying is that i have no inbox, but currently all thats in my DMS is my main account

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from your question that `GetDirectInboxAsync` was part of a third-party library.  I think I have found the [source code](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp) for the library you are talking about. In the latest source it doesn't appear that `IInstaApi` has a  `GetDirectInboxAsync` method on it.  Instead this method is on the `MessagingProcessor` class.  Are you using an old version?  If so I would suggest you upgrade to the latest and retry.  It's possible the problem was already addressed.

Comment: i downloaded the newest version from visual studio, and the messaging processor bit, i think it wouldnt make a diffrence,i think it was removed

Comment: and i have looked at that API sample, it is nearly identical, and it isnt working and spitting errors